# Json field match in Apache NiFi

Tags: json, regex, apache-nifi

I have a json coming as response from an InvokeHTTP like this:

```
{
   "id": "1234567890",
   "status": "completed",
   "others": "abc",
   "field": "1"
}
```

I would like to use a processor (maybe RouteOnAttribute??) that checks if the status of the response is completed and in case of un-match, it goes back to the invokeHttp to check status again.

I tried this thing:
**EvaluateJsonPath(to extract id from json) -> InvokeHTTP(to get status) -> RouteOnAttribute(to check status if completed)**

- -> match goes to a funnel
- -> unmatch goes to EvaluateJsonPath again (to create a loop)

**For the InvokeHTTP I need the original json file since I have to get the request id.**

I used Route to property name with the following attribute: status - ${status:equals('completed')}

unfortunately, I always receive an un-match even if the status is completed.

Where is the issue?

Comment: before routing you have to use evaluatejsonpath to extract "status" from json into flowfile attribute

Comment: Hi dagget, first I don't understand why you unvote my question....I asked a question that maybe for you is simple but I start working on nifi 1 week ago...by the way thanks for your comment

Comment: That was not me. I still can unvote your question, however I don't see any reason )

Comment: ok thanks dagget and I'm really sorry for the misunderstanding :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have built dummy flow, to check your case, see no issues. Here is the flow: [image]
Key points here:

1. In top EvaluateJsonPath i use flowfile-attribute as destination and add new property - status [image]
2. In RouteOnAttribute i check value of status [image]
3. In bottom EvaluateJsonPath i extract id, and as destination i use flowfile-content [image]

Answer (score 0):

In EvaluateJsonPath you need to set

property        value

---

status         .status

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).